# Need to understand use cases for JOINS - why join when you are interested in only part of the join?

Tags: sql

Okay this is not a programming question so feel free to downvote (Yay ! For the first time, I am encouraging such behavior - make the most of it).

But, I feel that it is important to know this. I have searched google and not seen one page which gives real world examples of why a particular join is needed.

I read this nice tutorial - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html 
My main issue is that if you join two tables and extract only part of it (example - 3, 4 th pic in link), then why are you joining in the first place ?

I need real example which show me the need to join two tables and then extract only one part of it.

Hurrah ! Let the down voting begin !

Comment: examples 3 and 4 are getting datas from both tables

Comment: my first -1 for the day ! I feel alive again :P

Comment: extra - http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/difference-between-a-left-outer-join-and-right-outer-join/
Should I use a right outer join or a left outer join?

Actually, it doesn’t matter. The right outer join does not add any functionality that the left outer join didn’t already have, and vice versa. All you would have to do to get the same results from a right outer join and a left outer join is switch the order in which the tables appear in the SQL statement. If that’s confusing, just take a closer look at the examples given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the JOIN is being used merely to determine the rows in one table that you're interested in. For instance, "tell me the names of all the people who live in green houses". If you have a table of people and a table of houses, you'll join them to determine who lives in each house, and use a WHERE clause that selects the green houses. But you'll only return names from the People table.

Answer (score 1):

You might join two tables together, even if you only want the columns from one of them, so that you can filter on the columns in the second table.

Example: Teachers table and students table. You only want a list of teachers names if they have at least 20 kids in their class. You join the two tables to find out how many students a teacher has, but you only select the name from the teachers table - very simple example.

Comment: Can you give me a real world use case scenario where you have to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Joins are (ideally) only done through 1 field, the foreign key, the purpose being to get at the row of data in the associated table.  Which fields you then use will vary, sometimes all, sometimes 1 but that is all after the join takes place.

Otherwise each field or set of fields would need its own key... which would put it in its own table.

The set of data for a given row is the data that is associated with that entity, so 'User' will have email, name, address, etc, etc. for  1 record with 1 key even if sometimes only 1 field is needed.